# Pass select_tag value to load query in the same view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this question has been answered before, but none of the methods had worked for me.

I have a view with a select_tag that loads options from my database.
 `<%= select_tag :nom, options_from_collection_for_select(Usuario.all, :id, :tienda), prompt: "Seleccionar tienda" %>`

then, I use a link_to `<%= link_to("Cargar", :action => 'rel') %><br>`to load the query on my controller

```
def rel
@nom = params[:nom]
@tie = Av.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM avm.avs where usuario_id in(select id from avm.usuarios where tienda = ?)", @nom])
render('rel')
```

The problem is that when I select any value on my select_tag it does not pass that value and sets the value to nil...

I also used a collection_select and doesn't work either. `<%= collection_select(:tienda, :tienda, Usuario.all, :id, :tienda)%>`

I really broke my head off trying to figure out why. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag action: rel do %>
  <%= select_tag :nom, options_from_collection_for_select(Usuario.all, :id, :tienda), prompt: "Seleccionar tienda" %>
  <br>
  <%= link_to("Cargar", '#', onclick: 'this.parentNode.submit(); return false') %>
<% end %>
```

Hint: replace `find_by_sql` by `Arel`:

```
@tie = Av.where("usuario_id IN (#{Usuario.select('id').where('tienda = ?', @nom).to_sql})")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put the `select_tag` in a `form_tag` block, and use `submit_tag` instead of `link_to`. If you just use a link no parameters will be passed to the controller (hence you get nil).

Something like:

```
<%= form_tag action: 'rel' do %>
    <%= select_tag :nom, options_from_collection_for_select(Usuario.all, :id, :tienda), prompt: "Seleccionar tienda" %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Cargar' %>
<% end %>
```

Just be mindful that this approach is not safe as there is no authenticity token verification.

Comment: the problem was that i was not using a form_tag. Thank you very much! This works!!